# imap_fetch returning garbage

Tags: php, email, imap

Im really confused on this, i have an email that is generated from a log file, it sends an email with the contents of the log file in the body.

I done some testing as im new to imap stuff and php in general on a test gmail account, with the following code i could see the whole body of hundreds of emails without issue:

```
$mailbox = "xxx@gmail.com";
$mailboxPassword = "xxxx";

$mailbox = imap_open("{imap.gmail.com:993/imap/ssl}INBOX", $mailbox, $mailboxPassword);

$mail = imap_search($mailbox,'ALL');

if(empty($mail)) die('No unread emails found!');

foreach ($mail as $key => $val) 
{

// Retrieving message headers
$headers = imap_headerinfo($mailbox, $val);

// Retrieving subject
$subject = $headers->subject;
```

p.s i can echo the subject and all is returned fine

```
 mb_internal_encoding("UTF-8");
 $subject = mb_decode_mimeheader(str_replace('_', ' ', $subject));

 $body_pre = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1);
 $body = $body_pre ? imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 2)) : imap_qprint(imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1));

 if (empty($body))
    {
    $body = $body_pre;  
    }
```

Now the code is probably messy, i basically took over someone elses code and made it work for me, i added the if empty one because some of the bodys was returning empty, once i added that it worked fine. I know its due to Russian/French encoding so although the info displays fine the russian/french characters dont display correctly but its at least not empty

Anyway basically what i done was took the original email, forwarded it to this test account, ran that code and if i echoed out $body i could see every email body.

Now the problem occurred when i took the exact same emails, there all the same email logs from a txt file basically sent as an email, but when i ran the same query on the inbox with basically only difference they have FW: in the subject well this is what the body outputted as:

> SE0yIENyYXNoIExvZyBDb250ZW50cyBCZWxvdzo8YnIgLz48YnIgLz5Vc2VyIEVtYWlsOiBBbm9u
>   LiAtIE5vdCBTdXBwbGllZDxhbm9uQGhvbGRlbW1hbmFnZXIuY29tPjxiciAvPkJ1aWxkIEluZm86
>   IDIuMC4wLjc2NjU8YnIgLz5Vc2VyIERlc2NyaXB0aW9uOiBOL0E8YnIgLz48YnIgLz5Mb2cgRmls
>   ZSBDb250ZW50czogPGJyIC8+PGJyIC8+MDE6MTI6MTMuMTEwIFtNYWluOjEgLSBVbml0eUJvb3Rz
>   dHJhcHBlci5SdW5dIDxiciAvPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICBfX18gICAg
>   ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxiciAvPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAg
>   ICAgICAgICggICApICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgIDxiciAvPg0KICAgICAg
>   ICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB8IHwgLi0uICAgIF9fXyAuLS4gLi0uICAgICAuLS0uICAg
>   IDxiciAvPg0KICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICAgICB8IHwvICAgXCAgKCAgICkgICAn

And body_pre echoes as empty

I tried changing to this also and echoing all these and they all displayed blank

```
$body_pre0 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val);
    $body_pre = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1);
    $body_pre1 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1.1);
    $body_pre2 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1.2);
    $body_pre3 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 2);
    $body_pre4 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 2.0);
    $body_pre5 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 2.1);
    $body_pre6 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 2.2);
    $body_pre7 = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 2.3);
    echo "Body 0: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre0 . "<br />";
    echo "Body 1: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre . "<br />";
    echo "Body 1.1: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre1 . "<br />";
    echo "Body 1.2: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre2 . "<br />";
    echo "Body 2: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre3 . "<br />";
    echo "Body 2.0: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre4 . "<br />";
    echo "Body 2.1: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre5 . "<br />";
    echo "Body 2.2: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre6 . "<br />";
    echo "Body 2.3: <br /><br /><br />" . $body_pre7 . "<br />";
```

Im a bit lost and would love a bit of guidance so i dont lose my mind before the new year :)

The email has a bunch of confidential stuff, i can add it with that all blanked out if it helps but i presume since the forwarded emails works and not the original its probably some encoding type issue or something obvious but let me know if adding that helps, most emails are huge so it would take a long time to edit all confidential info but can do if you request

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that doesn't look like garbage to me... it looks like base64 encoded html...

```
In [4]: print base64.b64decode(corpus)
HM2 Crash Log Contents Below:<br /><br />User Email: Anon. - Not Supplied<anon@holdemmanager.com><br />Build Info: 2.0.0.7665<br />User Description: N/A<br /><br />Log File Contents: <br /><br />01:12:13.110 [Main:1 - UnityBootstrapper.Run] <br />
                             ___                                <br />
                            (   )                               <br />
                             | | .-.    ___ .-. .-.     .--.    <br />
                             | |/   \  (   )   '
```

Comment: Aha looks like were getting somewhere but i still cant get the output i need, i tried editing it to this:

$body = $body_pre ? imap_base64(imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 2)) : imap_base64(imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1));

But same results?

Comment: ok i stripped out the qprint line and just done this and it worked, thanks for the hint

$body = imap_fetchbody($mailbox, $val, 1);
$body = base64_decode($body);